# How to automatically grant admin rights to a certain application?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, automation, administrator

I have this application and it needs admin rights (I am an admin already), but I need to run it very often and it's becoming quite annoying have to click "Yes" every time. Is there a way to prevent the popup and automatically grant the permission for this specific program?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I am an admin and none of those solve my problem

Comment: It does but that's not what I want, I want to disable the UAC for this specific program, not for every program

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to show/answer 1) why those related questions don't solve your problem (or at least that you've tried them, so that we know what you've tried and 2) which version of Windows you're on as that has relevance (as Ramhound mentioned). Cheers :)

Comment: The reason I commented is that as your question stands we don't know what you've tried or if you've even seen the other questions or not. We have to read the comments (which are meant to be temporary) to find out you looked at those and they didn't work- hence Ramhound suggesting it is a duplicate. No worries re the tag- someone else added the 'windows' tag which wasn't specific enough so I edited it to indicate Windows 10!

Comment: As it stands, I (and the SU community) still don't know *why* the other questions/answers didn't address your situation- only you can elaborate! :)

Comment: @MisterR.U.B.I, I came across your question because it is in a review queue.  I'm reading the comments and the proposed duplicate and scratching my head.  The proposed dupe seems to exactly address what you describe and your comments about why it doesn't seem to describe something different.  Is the issue that the solutions don't work for Win10?  The problem is that without clarification, any answers you get will just duplicate those on the other question because there isn't enough info here for people to understand how your requirement is different.

Comment: Basically the program I had to deal with had to re-run itself lots of times and that triggered the UAC prompt a lot. The solutions proposed involved a hack using task scheduler which would work if it didn't re-run itself. That being said the only solution I found was using TweakUAC.

Comment: Tags are simply used to file your question into a category.The body of the quesion should still contain which operating system your using.  The original revision of this question, didn't indicate any operating system, it was only after I mentioned it in a comment did somebody add an addtional tag.I should be clear, I only assume your using Windows 10, because there is no evidence to say otherwise.You should edit your question, that is the only way for us to be able to open this question again, so you can get an answer to your specific question.  I will be flagging the comments as "too chatty"